# How can I implement a show/hide functionality in the popup.html of a Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'd like to show/hide text...I understand the minimum basics of Manifest 2 and have successfully implemented a javascript dropdown menu that uses an eventlistener...

This simple code works when I open popup.html in Google as a website. It doesn't work in the actual extension (clicking the logo).

I think I need a listener or similar for security reasons...but don't know how to make it work.

The goal is to be able to show/hide blocks of text visible in the popup.html page that appears when you click the extension's logo/button in Chrome. Any help deeply appreciated...

HTML:

```
<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">show</a> <== click Here
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none"><h1>Hello world</h1></div>
```

JS:

```
 function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
    ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "show";
    }
    else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
    }
```

Update after question:

Thanks so much for responding...

It's a very straightforward Extension...yes, three files: manifest.json, popup.html and popup.js.

The popup shows when you click the icon - everything works great except the little bit of javascript to make show/hide work.

I don't get an error - it just doesn't work (maybe there's a way to see errors?). I think the security model is stopping the js from running.

The same thing happened with the simple drop-down menu, but I got around it by adding listeners to the js file. The example below WORKS for the jump menus...so I'm puzzling over how to allow the simple js in the show/hide code to work.

```
Function init() {

jump = document.getElementById('jumpchoice');   
jumpowl = document.getElementById('jumpchoiceowl'); 
jumpmla = document.getElementById('jumpchoicemla'); 
jumpapa = document.getElementById('jumpchoiceapa'); 


jump.addEventListener('change',jumpto,false);
jumpowl.addEventListener('change',jumptoowl,false);
jumpmla.addEventListener('change',jumptomla,false);
jumpapa.addEventListener('change',jumptoapa,false);

}    
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```

Comment: so, you have three files in your extension?(1)manifest.json(2)popup.html(3)popup.js(not background.js)Is it right? Also, does popup show up when you click the icon for either page action or browser action? What error are you getting? and what is your manifest.json like?

Comment: Thanks so much for responding...

It's a very straightforward Extension...yes, three files: manifest.json, popup.html and popup.js.

The popup shows when you click the icon - everything works great except the little bit of javascript to make show/hide work.

Comment: I added some detail to the original post...thank you for taking a look.

Comment: >maybe there's a way to see errors?
Yes, there is a way to see errors in popup.html.
Take a look at this page to learn how to debug for Chrome extension. http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html

Comment: Thanks...clicking on my js link ('show') throws an error related to security. Here it is: Refused to execute JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".

WHAT I DON'T SEE spelled out is how to add a listener for this type of event...just basic instructions on adding an eventlistener...THANKS for any help...

Comment: I think you can't insert inline javascript like this href="javascript:toggle(); To follow their Content Security Policy, You need to add an event listener in a javascript file not in a html file.

Comment: take a look at this section of the page. It explains you are not allowed to use inline javascript. http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question, but anyone landing on this page with a similar problem:

According to the docs on **[changes regarding Manifest V2](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2.html#inline_scripts)**:

> [...] inline event handlers [...] will not execute.
>
> These will not work in manifest V2 extensions. Remove the inline event handlers, place them in your external JS file and use addEventListener() to register event handlers for them instead

So, in your case, instead of:

```
<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">show</a>
```

you should do it like this:

```
/* In 'popup.html' */
<a id="displayText">show</a>

/* In 'popup.js' (after the DOM has beed loaded) */
document.getElementById("displayText").addEventListener("click", toggle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well don't know if you found an answer yet or not but here I go...
I just had this same type of issue myself.
You can go here > [jQueryUI](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/) < This helped me a lot.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>tabs demo</title>
// ***Start of jQueryUI***
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
// ***End of jQueryUI***
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#fragment-3"><span>Three</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div id="fragment-1">
<p>First tab is active by default:</p>
<pre><code>$( "#tabs" ).tabs(); </code></pre>
</div>
<div id="fragment-2">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
</div>
<div id="fragment-3">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
</div>
</div>

<script>    // ****This script will have to go in 'popup.js'****
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Also, note that JQuery is not at all necessary to solve the problem. ake a look at my answer explaining the problem (and solution) :)